# Spring Cloud Gateway to enhance JWT tokens from external OAuth Authorization Server

Tags: spring, cloud, spring-webflux, api-gateway

I have the following [Securing Services with Spring Cloud Gateway](https://spring.io/blog/2019/08/16/securing-services-with-spring-cloud-gateway) working with Keycloak. Expanding upon this I am routing to many Webflux Resources Servers.

However, the scopes provided by external Authorization servers are very simplistic. So I need to take the micro-service ID plus the User ID from the JWT and then check a database which then translates to their Team, which would then provide a list of accessible static pages and URL REST endpoints. So my resulting code would like something like;

```
...
  .matcher("/page1.html").hasAuthority("SERVICE1_PAGE1")
  .matcher("/page2.html").hasAuthority("SERVICE1_PAGE2")


@PreXXX("hasAuthority('SERVICE1_getAll'))
public List<String> getAll() {...}
```

I assume that I could do it at the micro-service level by [Extracting Authorities Manually](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction), but by doing this I would need to duplicate this code in every micro-service.

***Edit:*** This is what I am currently doing, by using a `WebClient` to call another common micro-service which returns the corrected authorities. However, if the URL of the authority micro-service is a Gateway address, the Gateway never attempts to resolve the URL. If I use it's explicit URL, I get 401 from the authority micro-service, even though I use `ServerBearerExchangeFilterFunction`. If I put `permitAll()` on the micro-service which returns the authorities, it works.

I could stand up my own Authorization server and use a `TokenEnhancer`. However, by doing so, I assume that I would need to load up all possible permissions for the user for every possible micro-service (as I do not know at this point where the user is going) and could result in a lot of data.

Ideally, I would like to centralise this in the Gateway and have the `TokenRelay` filter recognise the route and somehow enhance the token. Is this possible?

Can someone please recommend how best to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finally implemented using Spring 2.2.2 Cloud Gateway, Eureka and KeyCloak.

SECURITY micro-service.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/grantedAuthorities/{applicationName}/{userId}", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    // JWT not sent when called within jwtAuthenticationConverter, so pass user id as param !!
public Flux<String> getUsersApplicationAuthorities(@PathVariable String applicationName, @PathVariable String userId) {
    return Flux.fromIterable(roleRepository.getRolesByUserId(applicationName, userId));
}
```

This would return something like;

```
SCREEN1_READ
SCREEN2_WRITE
```

My OTHER micro-service.

```
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    @Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER)
    SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
            .authorizeExchange(exchanges ->
                exchanges                   
                    .pathMatchers("/screen1.html").hasAnyAuthority("SCREEN1_READ", "SCREEN1_WRITE")
                    .pathMatchers("/screen2.html").hasAnyAuthority("SCREEN1_READ", "SCREEN2_WRITE")
                    .anyExchange().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(spec ->
                spec.jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwt -> {

                /* ServerBearerExchangeFilterFunction does not work here! So I have to send userId instead of JWT */

                    WebClient webClient = loadBalancedWebClientBuilder().build();
                    String userId =  jwt.getClaimAsString("preferred_username").toUpperCase();
                    String uri = "lb://SECURITY/drs/grantedAuthorities/" + applicationName + "/" + userId;
                    return webClient.get().uri(uri)
                            .retrieve()
                            .bodyToFlux(String.class)
                            .map(s -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(s))
                            .doOnNext(l -> log.info("Has authority " + l))
                            .collectList()
                            .map(gaList -> new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, gaList));
                })
            )
            .csrf().disable()
            .cors().disable();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

For enabling/disabling buttons when in READ/WRITE for Thymeleaf;

```
@Controller
public class PageController {
    @GetMapping("/screen1.html")
    public String index(@AuthenticationPrincipal JwtAuthenticationToken jwt, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("update", jwt.getAuthorities().contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("SCREEN1_WRITE"))); 
        return "screen1";
    }
}
```

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="updateableScreen" th:attr="data-update=${update}"></div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

After which use JQuery/Javascript to change access to form controls by checking `$("#updateableScreen")`